# WinUI3 CheckBox content style

Tags: winrt-xaml, winui-3

I'm trying to change the color of a CheckBox text, but it doesn't work. Here is what I tried:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="OptionCheckBox"
          Foreground="#FFFFFFF"
          Content="PDF">
    <CheckBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize"
                    Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Padding"
                    Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                    Value="Left" />
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Resources>
</CheckBox>
```

Why doesn't it work, what can I use instead?

Comment: Does @emoacht 's solution work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the default Style as explained in [Where are the default WinUI3 control style files?](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6940). Reading generic.xaml, the Foreground is solely managed by VisualStateManager and so the Brush set in a Style would be overriden. I think Faywang's explanation on UWP in
[Checkbox content color can't be set in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60962788/3137337) can apply to WinUI as well.

That said, if you don't mind to fix the Brush, the easiest solution is to define a ContentTemplate in the Style and directly set Foreground of TextBlock.

```xml
<Style TargetType="CheckBox">
    ...
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Blue"
                           Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"/>                             
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Making the style based on DefaultCheckBoxStyle might be better not to lose the default style. `<Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultCheckBoxStyle}">`

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding As far as I have observed, unlike WPF, the remaning property values of default Style still apply without it in the case of UWP and WinUI.

Comment: It depends. In the case of `CheckBox`, at least in WinUI, if you don't create the style based on the `DefaultCheckBoxStyle`, you lose the default look, the rounded corner on the checkbox for example.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding I see. It's interesting.

Comment: Setting the `ContentTemlplate` directly to the `CheckBox` is another way to do this.